# Android - Realm relationship list with primary key

Tags: android, database, realm, relationship

ChatRoom:

```
public class ChatRoom extends RealmObject{

    @PrimaryKey
    int chatRoomID;

    RealmList<ChatMessage> chatMessages;


       //getters & setters ...
}
```

Message class:

```
public class ChatMessage extends RealmObject {

       int chatMessageID;

       String chatMessageContent;

       User author;
   //getters & setters ...

    }
```

User:

```
public class User extends RealmObject  {

    @PrimaryKey
    int Id;

    String Name;


       //getters & setters ...

}
```

Well the first time that the chatmessage is created is fine but in the second time I get an error: Value already exists: 5 [Id of the User]

How can I update the user object when is added to my chatmessage list instead of created a new one?

This is the way that I add a new chatMessage:

```
 mRealm.beginTransaction();
        ChatRoom chatRoom   =   mRealm.where(ChatRoom.class).equalTo("chatRoomID", chatRoomID)
                .findFirst();
        chatRoom.getChatMessages().add(chatMessage); // add to the list
        mRealm.commitTransaction();
```

Comment: How did you create the `chatMessage`?

Comment: ChatMessage ch = new ChatMessage(); ch.SetChatMessageID(someId); ch.setChatMessageContent("text"); ch.setChatMessageAuthor(author);

Answer (score 1):

It is because of `chatMessage` is a unmanaged `RealmObject` and it has the same primary key with one is saved by Realm already.

So if an object is unmanaged object, when added it to a managed `RealmList`, Realm will try to create it. And an exception will be thrown when an object with the same pk already exists.

To solve this, use `copyToRealmOrUpdate()` to get a managed `RealmObject` first then add it, like:

```
ChatMessage ch = new ChatMessage();
ch.SetChatMessageID(someId);
ch.setChatMessageContent("text");
ch.setChatMessageAuthor(author);

mRealm.beginTransaction();
ch = mRealm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(ch); // get/create a managed RealmObject
ChatRoom chatRoom = mRealm.where(ChatRoom.class).equalTo("chatRoomID", chatRoomID)
    .findFirst();
chatRoom.getChatMessages().add(ch); // add to the list
mRealm.commitTransaction();
```

Comment: what if I have to just update the chatmessage?If a have only a realmobject and I want to do something like chatRoom.setChatMessage(ch)? How can I do this